# menue driven program to perform the following queue operation using array en-queue, de-queue, count the number of elements and display in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

i need to make a C++ program for
menu driven program to perform the following queue operation using array en-queue, de-queue, count the number of elements and display in c++?
how to make this one ?
im very weak in c++ can anyone guide me or help me or link me to a complete program to study it and understand it?!!!
i tried but i coudnt do it so i really need help

is this right or not ?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void push(int st[],int data,int &top);      //declaring a push class
void disp(int st[],int &top);       //declaring display class
int pop(int st[],int &top);                       //declaring a pop class
int flg=0;
int top=-1,tos=-1;
int st[50];

void push(int st[],int data,int &top)          //push
{
    if(top==50-1)
    flg=0;
    else
    {
        flg=1;
        top++;
        st[top]=data;
    }
}

int pop(int st[],int &top)                      //pop
{
    int pe;
    if(top==-1)
    {
        pe=0;
        flg=0;
    }
    else
    {
        flg=1;
        pe=st[top];
        top--;
    }

    return(pe);
}

void disp(int st[],int &top)                //display
{
    int i;
    if(top==-1)
    {
        cout<<"\nStack is Empty";
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=top;i>=0;i--)
        cout<<"\t"<<st[i];
    }
}

void main()
{
    int dt,opt;                              // declare varible
    int q=0;
    clrscr();
    cout<<"\t\t\tStack operations";
    cout<<"\n\n\tMain Menu.........";
    cout<<"\n\n1.Push";
    cout<<"\n\n2.Pop";
    cout<<"\n\n3.Exit";
    cout<<"\n\n4.display";

    do                                     // useing do while for to make choice and select any options
    {
        cout<<"\n\n\tEnter Your Choice 1-4:";            //entering your choice
        cin>>opt;

        switch(opt)
        {
            case 1:
                cout<<"\nEnter the Element to be Push:";
                cin>>dt;
                push(st,dt,tos);

                if(flg==1)
                {
                    cout<<"the push is done";

                    if(tos==50-1)
                        cout<<"\nStack is Now Full";
                }
                else
                   cout<<"\nStack Overflow Insertion Not Possible";
            break;
            case 2:
                dt=pop(st,tos);
                if(flg==1)
                {
                    cout<<"\n\tData Deleted From the Stack is:"<<dt;
                    cout<<"\n \t pop is done";
                }
                else
                    cout<<"\nStack Empty,Deletio Not Possible:";
            break;
            case 3:
                q=1;
            break;
        default:
                            cout<<"\nWrong Choice Enter 1-3 Only";

        case 4:
                disp(st,tos);
        break;
        }
    } while(q!=1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a queue collection in the STL library which provides all of the functionality required above for you, if for some reason you are not allowed to use this then I suggest the following logic might be helpful

- when an item is popped from the front of the queue all other items must be copied down 1 element, use a for loop for this

E.g

```
for (int index = 1; index < arraySize; index++)
{
     if (item[index] == -1)
     {
         item[index-1] = -1;
         break;
     }

     item[index - 1] = item[index];
}
```

- when an element is deleted, all items that follow that item in the queue must be moved down 1 space, find the index of the element being deleted and use a for loop

E.g

```
for (int index = deletedItemIndex; index < arraySize; index++)
{
     if (item[index] == -1)
         break;

     item[index] = item[index + 1];
}
```

- when an item is added to the queue it is simply placed at the end of the queue, but not necessarily the end of the array (perhaps initialise all the array elements with -1 to start, that way you can easily test if you are at the end of the queue)

Comment: please NOTE that while this code is functional, it will break in at least one place, I will leave that for you to figure out ;). Also this is assuming a FIFO  (First In First Out) queue